# Two lines inside a cell of a table

Tags: tables, multirow

I'd like to remove the mathematical expression in red and put in a green location. How can I make this?

[image]

```
\begin{table}
    \centering
    \caption{Parameters $\phi_{11}^{*}$, $\phi_{22}^{*}$, $\phi_{12}^{*}$ and $\rho^{*}$ selected from  Scenarios 1-7}
    \label{tab:parameters_scenarios}
    \begin{tabular}{c|cccccc}
        \hline
        \multirow{8}{*}{Scenario 1 ($\phi_{11} = \phi_{22} = 5$)} & \multirow{2}{*}{Parameters} & \multicolumn{5}{c}{$\rho$} \\ \cline{3-7}
        && 0    & 0.3  & 0.5  & 0.7 & 0.9 \\ \hline
        &$\phi^{*}_{11}$             & 2.50  & 3.25  & 3.75  & 4.25 & 4.75 \\
        &$\phi^{*}_{22}$             & 10.0 & 7.00 & 5.00 & 3.00 & 1.00 \\
        &$\phi^{*}_{12}$             & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 \\
        &$\rho^{*}$                  & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 \\ \hline
        \multirow{4}{*}{Scenario 2}  &$\phi^{*}_{11}$  & 2.00  & 2.58  & 2.97  & 3.36 & 3.74 \\
        &$\phi^{*}_{22}$             & 8.00 & 5.68   & 4.13  & 2.58  & 1.03 \\
        &$\phi^{*}_{12}$             & -1.00 & -1.00 & -1.00 & -1.00 & -1.00 \\
        &$\rho^{*}$                  & -0.25 & -0.26 & -0.28 & -0.34 & -0.51 \\ \hline  
        \multirow{4}{*}{Scenario 3}   &$\phi^{*}_{11}$ & 2.00  & 2.58  & 2.97  & 3.36 & 3.74 \\
        &$\phi^{*}_{22}$             & 8.00 & 5.68 & 4.13 & 2.58 & 1.03 \\
        &$\phi^{*}_{12}$             & 1.00 & 1.00 & 1.00 & 1.00 & 1.00 \\
        &$\rho^{*}$                  & 0.25 & 0.26 & 0.28 & 0.34 & 0.51 \\ \hline
        \multirow{4}{*}{Scenario 4}  &$\phi_{11}$  & 6.25 & 4.75 & 3.75 & 2.75 & 1.75 \\
        &$\phi_{22}$             & 6.25 & 7.75 & 8.75 & 9.75 & 10.75 \\
        &$\phi_{12}$             & 3.75 & 3.75 & 3.75 & 3.75 & 3.75 \\
        &$\rho$                  & 0.60 & 0.62 & 0.65 & 0.72 & 0.86 \\ \hline
        \multirow{4}{*}{Scenario 5}  & $\phi_{11}$  & 5.75 & 4.59 & 3.81 & 3.03 & 2.26 \\
        &$\phi_{22}$             & 5.75 & 6.91 & 7.69 & 8.46 & 9.25 \\
        &$\phi_{12}$             & 4.25 & 4.25 & 4.25 & 4.25 & 4.25 \\
        &$\rho$                  & 0.74 & 0.75 & 0.78 & 0.84 & 0.93 \\ \hline
        \multirow{4}{*}{Scenario 6} &$\phi_{11}$  & 6.75  & 4.73  & 3.40  & 2.05 & 0.71 \\
        &$\phi_{22}$            & 6.75  & 8.76 & 10.10 & 11.44 & 12.79 \\
        &$\phi_{12}$            & -0.75 & -0.75 & -0.75 & -0.75 & -0.75 \\
        &$\rho$                 & -0.11 & -0.12 & -0.13 & -0.15 & -0.25 \\ \hline   
        \multirow{4}{*}{Scenario 7} & $\phi_{11}$ & 6.00 & 4.20 & 3.00 & 1.80 & 0.60 \\
        &$\phi_{22}$             & 6.00 & 6.80 & 9.00 & 10.20 & 11.40 \\
        &$\phi_{12}$             & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 \\
        &$\rho$                  & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 \\ \hline   
    \end{tabular}
    %\raggedright WNBA data
\end{table}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just used `\stackunder{}{}` from the `stackengine` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow,stackengine}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
    \centering
    \caption{Parameters $\phi_{11}^{*}$, $\phi_{22}^{*}$, $\phi_{12}^{*}$ and $\rho^{*}$ selected from  Scenarios 1-7}
    \label{tab:parameters_scenarios}
    \begin{tabular}{c|cccccc}
        \hline
        \multirow{8}{*}{\stackunder{Scenario 1}{($\phi_{11} = \phi_{22} = 5$)}} & \multirow{2}{*}{Parameters} & \multicolumn{5}{c}{$\rho$} \\ \cline{3-7}
        && 0    & 0.3  & 0.5  & 0.7 & 0.9 \\ \hline
        &$\phi^{*}_{11}$             & 2.50  & 3.25  & 3.75  & 4.25 & 4.75 \\
        &$\phi^{*}_{22}$             & 10.0 & 7.00 & 5.00 & 3.00 & 1.00 \\
        &$\phi^{*}_{12}$             & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 \\
        &$\rho^{*}$                  & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 \\ \hline
        \multirow{4}{*}{Scenario 2}  &$\phi^{*}_{11}$  & 2.00  & 2.58  & 2.97  & 3.36 & 3.74 \\
        &$\phi^{*}_{22}$             & 8.00 & 5.68   & 4.13  & 2.58  & 1.03 \\
        &$\phi^{*}_{12}$             & -1.00 & -1.00 & -1.00 & -1.00 & -1.00 \\
        &$\rho^{*}$                  & -0.25 & -0.26 & -0.28 & -0.34 & -0.51 \\ \hline  
        \multirow{4}{*}{Scenario 3}   &$\phi^{*}_{11}$ & 2.00  & 2.58  & 2.97  & 3.36 & 3.74 \\
        &$\phi^{*}_{22}$             & 8.00 & 5.68 & 4.13 & 2.58 & 1.03 \\
        &$\phi^{*}_{12}$             & 1.00 & 1.00 & 1.00 & 1.00 & 1.00 \\
        &$\rho^{*}$                  & 0.25 & 0.26 & 0.28 & 0.34 & 0.51 \\ \hline
        \multirow{4}{*}{Scenario 4}  &$\phi_{11}$  & 6.25 & 4.75 & 3.75 & 2.75 & 1.75 \\
        &$\phi_{22}$             & 6.25 & 7.75 & 8.75 & 9.75 & 10.75 \\
        &$\phi_{12}$             & 3.75 & 3.75 & 3.75 & 3.75 & 3.75 \\
        &$\rho$                  & 0.60 & 0.62 & 0.65 & 0.72 & 0.86 \\ \hline
        \multirow{4}{*}{Scenario 5}  & $\phi_{11}$  & 5.75 & 4.59 & 3.81 & 3.03 & 2.26 \\
        &$\phi_{22}$             & 5.75 & 6.91 & 7.69 & 8.46 & 9.25 \\
        &$\phi_{12}$             & 4.25 & 4.25 & 4.25 & 4.25 & 4.25 \\
        &$\rho$                  & 0.74 & 0.75 & 0.78 & 0.84 & 0.93 \\ \hline
        \multirow{4}{*}{Scenario 6} &$\phi_{11}$  & 6.75  & 4.73  & 3.40  & 2.05 & 0.71 \\
        &$\phi_{22}$            & 6.75  & 8.76 & 10.10 & 11.44 & 12.79 \\
        &$\phi_{12}$            & -0.75 & -0.75 & -0.75 & -0.75 & -0.75 \\
        &$\rho$                 & -0.11 & -0.12 & -0.13 & -0.15 & -0.25 \\ \hline   
        \multirow{4}{*}{Scenario 7} & $\phi_{11}$ & 6.00 & 4.20 & 3.00 & 1.80 & 0.60 \\
        &$\phi_{22}$             & 6.00 & 6.80 & 9.00 & 10.20 & 11.40 \\
        &$\phi_{12}$             & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 \\
        &$\rho$                  & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 \\ \hline   
    \end{tabular}
    %\raggedright WNBA data
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

it also can be done with `makecell` macro from the package of the same name.

for this table i would use `S` column type from the package `siunitx` for aligning numbers at decimal points, rules from the package `booktabs` and not use vertical rules:

[image]

**edit:** as suggested [Bernard](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/38908/bernard) in his comment below, the code can be simple with use the macro `\multirowcell{4}{...}` instead of the `multirow{4}{*}{\makecell{...}}` cell's environment. this suggestion is now considered in mwe below:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, multirow}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[skip=1ex]{caption}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
    \centering
\caption{Parameters $\phi_{11}^{*}$, $\phi_{22}^{*}$, $\phi_{12}^{*}$ and $\rho^{*}$ selected from  Scenarios 1-7}
\label{tab:parameters_scenarios}
    \begin{tabular}{c
                >{$}c<{$}
               *{5}{S[table-format=-1.2]}
                    }
        \toprule
    & \multirow{2.2}{*}{Parameters} & \multicolumn{5}{c}{$\rho$}  \\
        \cmidrule(l){3-7}
    &                   & 0     & 0.3   & 0.5   & 0.7   & 0.9   \\
        \midrule
\multirowcell{4}{Scenario 1\\$(\phi_{11} = \phi_{22} = 5)$}}
    & \phi^{*}_{11}     & 2.50  & 3.25  & 3.75  & 4.25  & 4.75  \\
    & \phi^{*}_{22}     & 10.0  & 7.00  & 5.00  & 3.00  & 1.00  \\
    & \phi^{*}_{12}     & 0.00  & 0.00  & 0.00  & 0.00  & 0.00  \\
    & \rho^{*}          & 0.00  & 0.00  & 0.00  & 0.00  & 0.00  \\ \midrule
\multirowcell{4}{Scenario 2}
    & \phi^{*}_{11}     & 2.00  & 2.58  & 2.97  & 3.36  & 3.74  \\
    & \phi^{*}_{22}     & 8.00  & 5.68  & 4.13  & 2.58  & 1.03  \\
    & \phi^{*}_{12}     & -1.00 & -1.00 & -1.00 & -1.00 & -1.00 \\
    & \rho^{*}          & -0.25 & -0.26 & -0.28 & -0.34 & -0.51 \\ \midrule
\multirowcell{4}{Scenario 3}
    & \phi^{*}_{11}     & 2.00  & 2.58  & 2.97  & 3.36  & 3.74  \\
    & \phi^{*}_{22}     & 8.00  & 5.68  & 4.13  & 2.58  & 1.03  \\
    & \phi^{*}_{12}     & 1.00  & 1.00  & 1.00  & 1.00  & 1.00  \\
    & \rho^{*}          & 0.25  & 0.26  & 0.28  & 0.34  & 0.51  \\ \midrule
\multirowcell{4}{Scenario 4}
    & \phi_{11}         & 6.25  & 4.75  & 3.75  & 2.75  & 1.75  \\
    & \phi_{22}         & 6.25  & 7.75  & 8.75  & 9.75  & 10.75 \\
    & \phi_{12}         & 3.75  & 3.75  & 3.75  & 3.75  & 3.75  \\
    & \rho              & 0.60  & 0.62  & 0.65  & 0.72  & 0.86  \\ \midrule
\multirowcell{4}{Scenario 5}
    &  \phi_{11}        & 5.75  & 4.59  & 3.81  & 3.03  & 2.26  \\
    & \phi_{22}         & 5.75  & 6.91  & 7.69  & 8.46  & 9.25  \\
    & \phi_{12}         & 4.25  & 4.25  & 4.25  & 4.25  & 4.25  \\
    & \rho              & 0.74  & 0.75  & 0.78  & 0.84  & 0.93  \\ \midrule
\multirowcell{4}{Scenario 6}
    & \phi_{11}         & 6.75  & 4.73  & 3.40  & 2.05  & 0.71  \\
    & \phi_{22}         & 6.75  & 8.76  & 10.10 & 11.44 & 12.79 \\
    & \phi_{12}         & -0.75 & -0.75 & -0.75 & -0.75 & -0.75 \\
    & \rho              & -0.11 & -0.12 & -0.13 & -0.15 & -0.25 \\ \midrule
\multirowcell{4}{Scenario 7}
    & \phi_{11}         & 6.00  & 4.20  & 3.00  & 1.80  & 0.60  \\
    & \phi_{22}         & 6.00  & 6.80  & 9.00  & 10.20 & 11.40 \\
    & \phi_{12}         & 0.00  & 0.00  & 0.00  & 0.00  & 0.00  \\
    & \rho              & 0.00  & 0.00  & 0.00  & 0.00  & 0.00  \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @Bernard, indeed! i forgot on this `makecell` macro. i will edit my answer and consider your comment! thank you very much!